# SwiftUI: Cancel TapGesture on parent view

Tags: swiftui, gesture, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have view hierarchy in SwiftUI like

```
ParentView { 
//other views

ChildView().highPriorityGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                        print("Tap!")
                    })
// other views 
}self.gesture(tap)
```

And I want to have parent view handle all taps on the screen in spite of cases when user taps onto ChildView. Now both closures executes. 
How to stop tap gesture events propagating up view hierarchy?

Comment: A bit confused... Why then you added `highPriorityGesture` to `ChildView` if you don't want to handle it?

Comment: I do not want to Parent View has gesture recognized if tap is over Child view Rectangle. Parent View covers entire screen ex List and Child View is just cell in this list. I want to be tap recognized on entire screen inspite of this single Child View Cell. I consider addition of higher priority gesture block lower priority gesture but it doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 8):

Well, probably there is some specific in which exactly `ChildView` and `ParentView`, because as tested below (Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2) child view gesture just overrides parent view gesture.

Here is demo.. tapped in yellow area, then tapped in green area - no mix callbacks

[image]

Complete module code

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestGesturesPriority: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .gesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                    print(" -- child")
                })
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
        .background(Color.green)
        .gesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
            print(">> parent")
        })
    }
}
```

**Update:** variant for `List-Row`

Yeees... *List (Parent) - Row (Child)* case appeared very challenging... please find below approach, it looks weird but tested & works

```
struct TestGesturesPriority: View {

    let parentGesture = TapGesture().onEnded { // just for convenience
        print(">> parent")
    }
    
    @GestureState private var captured = false
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Hello, World!").padding()
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                    .allowsHitTesting(true)
                    .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0) // mimic Tap
                        .updating($captured, body: { (value, state, transaction) in
                        state = true // mark captured (will be reset automatically)
                    })
                    .onEnded { value in
                        // like Tap, but can be ignored if delta 
                        // is large or out of view
                        print(" -- child")
                    }
                )
        }
        .gesture(parentGesture, including: captured ? .subviews : .gesture)
    }
}
```

To summarise - actually I think it is another List defect

Comment: Maybe inside List (Parent) > Row  (Child) something works differently?

Comment: @MichałZiobro, see **Update** part

Comment: It is crazy that getting the child to cancel the gesture from traversing to the parent is **this** difficult -- but you saved the day!

Comment: I cannot get the same behaviour with Map and it's annotation. Meaning: I tap the annotation, the it first triggers the Map's onTap action, then triggers the annotation's onTap action. Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 3):

There's a slightly cleaner way to solve the tap localisation issue in `List` as follows:

```
struct TestListGestures: View {

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Hello, World!").padding()
                    .background(Color.yellow)

              .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.001) // resolve response time
                    .onEnded { value in
                        print(" -- child")
                    }
                )
        }
        .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.001).onEnded({ _ in
          print(" -- parent")
        }), including: .gesture)
    }
}
```