# SwiftUI ScrollView's onTapGesture getting called for child events

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I stumbled upon an event bubbling problem related to SwiftUI's `ScrollView` and have been able to reduce it to a short snippet of code. Please see below:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView() {
      Rectangle()
      .fill(Color.red)
      .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
      .onTapGesture {
        print("Rectangle onTapGesture")
      }
    }
    .onTapGesture {
      print("ScrollView onTapGesture")
    }
  }
}
```

When tapping outside of the Rectangle, I see in the console:

`ScrollView onTapGesture`

However, when tapping the Rectangle, I see two lines being printed:

`ScrollView onTapGesture`

`Rectangle onTapGesture`

The ScrollView seems to be responding to its child's event as well... that's not supposed to happen, right? What can I do to stop this?

EDIT: just to add to the madness, these two lines don't always appear in the same order! I've seen them swapped when restarting the app without any changes to the code.

My goal was to use an onTapGesture on the ScrollView to catch "dismissing" taps i.e., taps that were not caught/handled by any of the ScrollView's children.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Check this post out, specifically about handling this for for a List: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59946147/swiftui-cancel-tapgesture-on-parent-view It does indeed look like an ongoing bug

Comment: did my solution work for you? if so, please accept and upvote the answer. thanks!

Comment: @PranavKasetti unfortunately it didn't. Did it work for you when you tested it? See my comment to your answer.

Comment: Ahh ok, it was too responsive for taps but works for other gestures. Updated answer.

Comment: Did my new solution work for you?

Comment: Would you mind explaining which of the TapGestures should be replaced by the LongPressGesture? If you could update your code that would be best. Thank you!

Comment: Updated. I replaced both tap gesture recognisers. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a straightforward solution using `GeometryReader` and a `VStack` container for your `ScrollView` content:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { contentView in
      ScrollView {
        VStack {
          Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .onTapGesture {
              print("Rectangle onTapGesture")
          }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: contentView.size.width, minHeight: contentView.size.height, alignment: .top)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture {
          print("ScrollViewArea onTapGesture")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives you a `VStack` container that is always exactly the same size as its parent `ScrollView` because of the dynamic values we get from `GeometryReader`'s `size` property.

Note that the `alignment: .top` on this container is there to make it behave like a normal `ScrollView` would, anchoring scrolling items to the top. The added bonus is that if you remove that `alignment` attribute your scrolling items will start from the middle of the screen—something I've found to be impossible to do before stumbling on that solution. This could be interesting UX-wise as shorter lists could make sense to be centered vertically. I digress.

Final note is the `.contentShape` modifier being used to make the new `VStack`'s empty space tappable, which fixes your problem.

This idea was taken from this *Hacking with Swift* [ScrollView effects using GeometryReader article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/scrollview-effects-using-geometryreader) outlining how you can push this idea to another level, transforming elements as you scroll. Very fun stuff!

Answer (score 4):

`Gesture` in SwiftUI works differently to how `UITapGestureRecognizer` previously worked. i.e it recognises gestures simultaneously by default. If you want to capture only certain gestures with precedence, then you need to use an `ExclusiveGesture` view modifier onto a gesture, and not use the default `onTapGesture`.

`TapGesture` erroneously detected touches as it's too responsive (it has a minuscule minimum duration ~ 0.0001s). I easily fixed this by replacing `TapGesture` with a more reasonable `minimumDuration`:

`LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.001)`

Note that you can reduce or increase the minimum duration as per your needs, but this was the most stable when I tested.

This is probably a **SwiftUI bug** by the way, and I would encourage you to file a bug report outlining the issue.

Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

  var tap: some Gesture {
    LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.001)
      .exclusively(before: scrollTap)
      .onEnded { _ in
        print("Rectangle onTapGesture")
    }
  }

  var scrollTap: some Gesture {
    LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.001)
      .onEnded { _ in
        print("ScrollView onTapGesture")
    }
  }

  var body: some View {
    ScrollView() {
      Rectangle()
      .fill(Color.red)
      .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
      .gesture(tap)
    }.gesture(scrollTap, including: .gesture)

  }
}
```

If you have multiple views you want to exclusively ignore, use the `exclusively` view modifier multiple times (chained), or the `sequenced` if you want to reverse the capturing order. You can check the [Gesture docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gesture) for details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just tried the solution you posted -- I'm testing this in a project with nothing but this ContentView. Unfortunately, tapping the Rectangle still produces the "ScrollView onTapGesture" output. Not only that, but the sequence of output is unpredictable! Here's the output after tapping the Rectangle 3 times: ```ScrollView onTapGesture
Rectangle onTapGesture
Rectangle onTapGesture
ScrollView onTapGesture
ScrollView onTapGesture
Rectangle onTapGesture
ScrollView onTapGesture
Rectangle onTapGesture
```. What did you get when you tested it?

Comment: I had a bug which i’ve fixed now as i was writing this a bit hastily. See the new exclusively ordering and recogniser.

Comment: Which TapGesture should be replaced by the `LongPressGesture` with the `minimumDuration`? Would you mind updating your code example with the version that works for you? Also, great point on filing this bug. I did submit it about 10 days ago, but no news yet (I imagine these things take a while..?)

Comment: Bug reports do take time, I imagine the SwiftUI team has quite a few at the moment.. :)

Comment: Updated the code for both gestures, should work well now.

Comment: Hey, this does work, thank you! I'm not sure that I'm ready to replace all children tap gestures with `LongPressGesture` (especially since they will also need access to the parent's scrollTap gesture object), but this works as a proof of concept for now! Thanks again