# SwiftUI: can a child view suppress its parent view's contextMenu?

Tags: swiftui

I have a `.contextMenu` on a large view in my SwiftUI app. Inside is a child view with an `.onLongPressGesture`.

On iOS, context menus are triggered by a long press. So pressing the smaller view always triggers *both* the context menu and my own `LongPressGesture`.

I'd like to stop my little view from triggering the parent's context menu.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var swap: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Press the smaller view to swap colors")
                .padding()
                .background { swap ? Color.blue : Color.red }
                .onLongPressGesture { swap.toggle() }
        
            Text("Press the larger view for context menu")
                .padding()
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding()
        .background { swap ? Color.red : Color.blue }
        .contextMenu { Text("Menu Goes Here") }
    }
}
```

[image: A large red rectangle containing a small blue rectangle. The smaller rectangle says “press the smaller view to swap colors” and the larger says “press the outer box for context menu”]

Things I've tried:

- Using `.highPriorityGesture` makes no difference
- All the different `GestureMask` options affect subviews, not superviews
- A `LongPressGesture` with a short duration ensures my custom gesture triggers first, but doesn't prevent the menu from appearing
- A `DragGesture` with a zero minimum distance does the same as above
- The solution outlined in [SwiftUI: Cancel TapGesture on parent view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59946147/swiftui-cancel-tapgesture-on-parent-view) involves 2 gestures that are both under the author's control, so they can pick a winner. The context menu's internals are opaque to me.

Is there a way for a subview to prevent gestures bubbling up to its superviews?

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally suppress the `.contextMenu` by wrapping all its content in `if` block, because an empty menu won't ever appear:

```
.contextMenu {
    if !isPressingSmallerView {
        Text("Menu Goes Here")
    }
}
```

Then the trick to setting `isPressingSmallerView` is to use `.updating()` on our `LongPressGesture`:

```
.gesture(
    LongPressGesture()
        .updating($isPressingSmallerView) { value, state, _ in
            state = value
        }
        .onEnded { _ in
            swap.toggle()
        }
)
```

The complete solution in context:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @GestureState var isPressingSmallerView: Bool = false
    @State var swap: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Press the smaller view to swap colors")
                .padding()
                .background { swap ? Color.blue : Color.red }
                .gesture(
                    LongPressGesture()
                        .updating($isPressingSmallerView) { value, state, _ in
                            state = value
                        }
                        .onEnded { _ in
                            swap.toggle()
                        }
                )
        
            Text("Press the larger view for context menu")
                .padding()
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding()
        .background { swap ? Color.red : Color.blue }
        .contextMenu {
            if !isPressingSmallerView {
                Text("Menu Goes Here")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a small contrived example, so the `@GestureState` variable is local to the `ContentView`.

Depending on your view hierarchy, you may want to pass that state up from child to parent with a `PreferenceKey`